# Ember Data hasMany on AMS not saving

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I have an ember app and there are 2 models which have hasMany options in them. Basically they have a HABTM relationship. I have AMS in the backend rails REST API.

Here goes

```
App.Group = App.Subject.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  groupDesc: DS.attr 'string'
  createdAt: DS.attr 'date'
  users: DS.hasMany 'user'
  selected:false
  members: (->
    users = @get('users')
    if users then users.get 'length' else 0
  ).property('users')

App.Subject = DS.Model.extend
  roleAssignments: DS.hasMany 'roleAssignment'

App.User = App.Subject.extend
  fname: DS.attr 'string', defaultValue:''
  lname: DS.attr 'string', defaultValue:''
  email: DS.attr 'string', defaultValue:''
  position: DS.attr 'string'
  isSuperAdmin: DS.attr 'boolean'
  groups: DS.hasMany 'group'
```

When I try to create an object like this

```
user1 = @store.find(1)
user2 = @store.find(2)
role1 = @store.find(1)
role2 = @store.find(2)

roleAssignment1 = @store.createRecord('roleAssignment',{role:role1})
roleAssignment2 = @store.createRecord('roleAssignment',{role:role2})


group = @store.createRecord 'group', {name:'Test'}
group.get('users').pushObject(user1)
group.get('users').pushObject('user1)
group.get('roleAssignments').pushObject(roleAssignment1)
group.get('roleAssignments').pushObject(roleAssignment2)

When I save this group it posts the following into the server

group.save()

{"group":{"name":"Test","title":null,"group_desc":null,"created_at":null}}
```

Where is the rest of the data. I thought as per https://github.com/kaukas/data/commit/d55a30e3c07139d8aa034dfffd535fccae512ce1, this issue is solved in AMS for Ember data.

### Update

The users are getting reflected now for some reason (js caching, etc) but the role_assignments_id are coming as role_assignment_ids:["0"]

Do I need to create this before attaching it to the group